# How do I make image texture with random pattern and not symmetrical?

Tags: image, texture-coordinates

On the X axis my world of warcraft style bark texture has a symmetrical effect. That and the base of the tree doesn't seem to be following the curvature of the roots and I don't know how to make the pattern look random is there a way to give it a naturally look?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the free *Anti-Seam* addon, it is explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xNnuZjD9bK0), the addon is available [here](https://thatimster.gumroad.com/l/juLNpq). You can also try [this addon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VgtSL5ZpYc) created by Blender Guru.

A trick would be to mix the texture with itself with a *Noise Texture* as factor, the second version being scaled up a bit. Let's say that it is your basic texture, we can see that it is repeated:

[image]

Create this node setup:

[image]

Now the repetition is much less noticeable as the pattern is mixed with a larger version of itself:

[image]

Comment: There were two files, I'm not sure which I'm supposed to download so I chose both I even kept them as a zip file but when I tried to install the addon and went to user I couldn't see it anywhere in addons.

Comment: I've only uploaded the 1.1 version and t works for me in 3.6.4 (I can see and activate it in the addons list but I don't know how it works though)

Comment: Ok I see the anti-seam add-on and I checked it, but I don't see texture tools in shader editer.

Comment: if it doesn't work, Blender Guru has made an addon: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VgtSL5ZpYc

Comment: but I'm going to propose a trick

Comment: Thanks, but the addon is working I just logged out of blender, waited then all of a sudden it worked I guess the problem solved itself I don't know how, could've been an error.

Comment: OK, great then......  :)

Comment: Also is there a way for the textures to match the roots of the base?

Comment: Not sure what ypu mean

Comment: Sorry I mean how do I make the texture copy the shape and direction of the roots so that the bark pattern looks like it's moving to one end point per root.